# fetch meta fields inside a widget

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, post-meta

I'm trying to fetch a (date) meta field from a custom post type in a sidebar widget here: http://www.oransje.com/utvikling/ngnf/kurs/

Somehow the date doesn't show correctly inside the widget (everywhere else I put it, also manually in the sidebar the code works fine). Anyone a clue?

The code looks like this:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array( 
'post_type' => 'kurs', 
'posts_per_page' => '5',
'meta_key' => 'dato',
'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
'meta_compare' => '>=',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
 )); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php $display_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, "dato", true))); ?>

<li><?php echo $display_date; ?> - <?php the_title( '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a>' ); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding: global $post;

Comment: Please add this as answer.

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 1 hour. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding:

```
global $post;
```

More specific: I can't explain why this works, that's beyond my WordPress skills, but I added it right after the start of the query, so the code looks like this:

```
<?php global $post; 
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type' => 'kurs', 
'posts_per_page' => '5',
'meta_key' => 'dato',
'meta_value' => date('Y-m-d'),
'meta_compare' => '>=',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
 ) ); ?>
```